# API Authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, rest, cookies

I am building a Spring Boot service that is supposed to call to an external API, and then send the fetched data to the client-side. To send any requests, I must first authenticate by sending a POST request with specific data in the request body, which then sends back a response with authentication key as a cookie. I've made it work in Postman but don't know how to do this in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have something similar to this:
The main ideea is to use a rest template.

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        try {
             String result = restTemplate.postForEntity(externalAPIUrl, entity, String.class).getBody();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {          
             if (ex.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
             }               
        }
```